# Inner Join and Where clause doesnot not displaying any info

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT tc.number, tc.created, staff.firstname, staff.lastname,tde.title
FROM ost_ticket AS tc 
INNER JOIN ost_thread AS td ON tc.ticket_id = td.object_id
INNER JOIN ost_thread_entry AS tde ON tc.staff_id = tde.thread_id
INNER JOIN ost_staff AS staff ON tc.staff_id = staff.staff_id
WHERE DATE(tc.created) = CURDATE() GROUP BY tc.number ORDER BY tc.created DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

If I remove the WHERE and GROUP BY clauses I get the proper results but I need to filter with the WHERE for current date and need to group the results by Number.

I have given the tables alternate names but if I try and query date and group I get no results displayed. I am not sure if the alternate names is the issue here.

The two coulombs is in ost_ticket Table that I need to use.

Working:

```
SELECT staff.firstname, staff.lastname, th.created, ost_ticket.number, the.title
FROM ost_ticket 
INNER JOIN ost_thread AS th ON ost_ticket.ticket_id = th.object_id
INNER JOIN ost_thread_entry AS the ON th.id = the.thread_id
INNER JOIN ost_staff AS staff ON ost_ticket.staff_id = staff.staff_id
WHERE DATE(ost_ticket.created) = CURDATE() GROUP BY number ORDER BY ost_ticket.created DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

I used the above code and got it to work

Answer (score 0):

You are using  group in wrong way. the use of group by without aggregation function is deprecated  in SQL and don't work in most DB and  don't work in most recent mysql version. And i addition remember that the use fo group by without aggregation function return unpredictable result for the column s not involved  in group  by

if you need distinct result then add  distinct clause

```
  SELECT DISTINCT tc.number, tc.created, staff.firstname, staff.lastname,tde.title
  FROM ost_ticket AS tc 
  INNER JOIN ost_thread AS td ON tc.ticket_id = td.object_id
  INNER JOIN ost_thread_entry AS tde ON tc.staff_id = tde.thread_id
  INNER JOIN ost_staff AS staff ON tc.staff_id = staff.staff_id
  WHERE DATE(tc.created) = CURDATE() 
  ORDER BY tc.created DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

otherwise if you need  group by add (fake)  aggreagtion function

```
SELECT tc.number, min(tc.created), min(taff.firstname), min(staff.lastname), min(tde.title)
FROM ost_ticket AS tc 
INNER JOIN ost_thread AS td ON tc.ticket_id = td.object_id
INNER JOIN ost_thread_entry AS tde ON tc.staff_id = tde.thread_id
INNER JOIN ost_staff AS staff ON tc.staff_id = staff.staff_id
WHERE DATE(tc.created) = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY tc.number ORDER BY tc.created DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: It is still not displaying any results I have used your exact code above, once I remove the WHERE DATE section it sends results

Comment: then  add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..but if  you get the correct result removing where then check for the real filtering values .. could be you have not value for tc.created  that match curdate()

Comment: My tc.created is 2014-10-3008:15:51 and it is populated, still do not get any information displayed

Comment: 2014-10-30 08-15:51  is not curdate()   alias  2017-10-30  ... so  you could use date(tc.created)  = str_to_date('2014-10-30', '%Y-%m-%d')  ..or date(tc.created)  = curdate()